# cx_freeze and importing modules

Tags: python, compilation, executable, cx-freeze, python-module

I want to compile a Python 3.3 module with submodules using cx_freeze.

So, my dir strucuture is:

```
projectname/
     __init__.py
     submodule1/
          __init__.py
          bootstrap.py
          script1.py
          submodule11/
                   script2.py
     submodule2/
          ...
```

In the `__init__.py` I import

```
from submodule1 import bootstrap
```

and from the bootstrap

```
import submodule1.submodule11.script2
```

If I run the init file, anything is good and the script with the submodule imports is executed correctly.

When I compile it, I use this setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import sys

includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ['submodule1', 'submodule2']
base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = 'myapp',version = '0.1',description = 'app',author = 'user',
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages}}, 
    executables = [Executable('__init__.py',base=base)]
)
```

and run the script in the 'projectname' dir.

But if I start the application I get `ImportError: no module named 'submodule1.submodule11'` from an error dialog.

And it's true: in the library.zip this submodule doens't exist.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show the output from freezing it? It will be long, put it in a pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found the answer: every module MUST have a `__init__.py` file in it's folder so python would know that it's a package, not just some folder. Now I compile my project.

Comment: Could you explane more?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details for anyone who has the same problems.

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├─ dir1
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   ├─ __pycache__ 
│   ├─ file1.kv
│   └─ file1.py
├─ dir2
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   ├─ __pycache__
│   ├─ file2.kv
│   └─ file2.py
├─ favicon.ico
├─ main.kv
├─ main.py
├─ setup.py
├─ venv
└─ y
```

In every directory module I add `__init__.py`

Since the module is located in `dir1` and `dir2`, so here is my `__init__.py` file.

**`__init__.py` in dir1:**

```py
from dir1 import file1
```

**`__init__.py` in dir2:**

```py
from dir2 import file2
```

**Here is my `setup.py` file:**

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = ["kivy", "datetime", "time", "re", "dir1.file1","dir2.file2"],
                    excludes = [], include_files = ["main.kv", "dir1/file1.kv", "dir2/file2.kv"])


base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, targetName='testApp', icon='favicon.ico')
]

setup(name='Test Apps',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'This is the Testing Python Apps with Kivy',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

This is GUI python apps testing with Kivy, that is why I included "kivy" in the packages.

After it has compiled you will have `Build` folder and subfolder  for the executable files. In my laptop there is `build/exe.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8`

cz_freeze only compiles python file, meanwhile I need `file1.kv` and `file2.kv` for GUI layout, so I create `dir1` and `dir2` manually in `build/exe.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8` and moved `file1.kv` and `file2.kv` to each folder.