# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind' in using cx_freeze

Tags: python, oop, attr, distutils, cx-freeze

I have a project in this structure on my linux machine:

```
project/
       changelog
       README
       src/
          install.sh
          myproject.py
          modules/
                 a.py 
                 b.py
                 __init__.py
```

Now I want to use `cx_freeze` for building my project:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['changelog', 'README', 'src/install.sh']
executable = ['src/myproject.py', 'src/modules/a.py',  'src/modules/b.py', 'src/modules/__init__.py']
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = []

setup(
    name = 'myproject',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A general enhancement utility',
    author = 'user',
    author_email = 'mail@gmail.com',
    options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [Executable(executable)]
```

I do:

```
$ python setup.py build
```

But the following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign an array to `executable` variable

```
executable = ['src/myproject.py', 'src/modules/a.py',  'src/modules/b.py', 'src/modules/__init__.py']
```

but it should be a string. Please refer to [manual](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils). An example from the manual:

```
setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: Instead of `"guifoo.py"` (i.e. a string) you assign `['src/myproject.py', 'src/modules/a.py',  'src/modules/b.py', 'src/modules/__init__.py']` (i.e. an array). And an array does not have `rfind` method defined. I don't know how to say it more clearly. Maybe try to reformulate your question if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: So how can I change it?

Comment: I believe it should be `executable="src/myproject.py"` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895636/how-do-i-use-cx-freeze)

Comment: Ok..But other modules aren't copied...like src/modules/a.py ETC

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938252/cx-freeze-and-importing-modules looks like a similar question to yours.